# Are there mux/demux chips that will enable N-signals to be connected in arbitrary configurations?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Would like to be able to configure a small number of signals, in this case 3 signals, A, B, and C, for testing, with arbitrary connections.

Not looking for a CPLD or FPGA, would prefer an IC.

Use case is to be able to things like A->B, A->C for one test, or C->A, C->B for another test, or B->A, B->C for another test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The component type you're looking for is a crosspoint switch IC.

They connect a number of A-side pins to a number of B-side pins in a programmable arrangement.

Analogue and digital versions exist, you can research them further on the Internet. The site's not for individual part recommendations but this is a technology.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of such a component, appreciate it!